# Jekyll - Image path works during jekyll serve, not on live site

Tags: jekyll

I changed my _config.yml file to:

```
baseurl: "/pages"
```

That's where we're storing our pages. When I do `jekyll serve` on my localhost, everything is fine. The image path shows up as:

```
 <img src="assets/images/foo/foo-icon.png">
```

Then I pushed it, and it doesn't work on our live site. The image path is this instead:

```
<img src="/pages/assets/images/foo/foo-icon.png">
```

If I change the path to the following, it works:

```
<img src="../assets/images/foo/foo-icon.png">
```

How do I get Jekyll to give me the right image path?

Answer (score 0):

If you are serving your site at http://example.com/ rather than http://example.com/pages/, then you don't want to set `baseurl`. https://byparker.com/blog/2014/clearing-up-confusion-around-baseurl/

Comment: This fixed it. It looks like I just needed to add `{{ site.baseurl }}` to the front of my image paths, without setting a baseurl in _config.yml. Now it works!